# Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson, postman

I tried to fetch all students (Etudiant) from EtudianController and received this error This is my Model Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "etudiant")
@JsonIgnoreType
public class Etudiant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long numInscription;
private String nameETU;
private String prenomETU;
private String adresseETU;
@CreationTimestamp
private Date dateEntree;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "course_etudiant", joinColumns = @JoinColumn, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn)
private List<Cours> listCours;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listEtudiant")
private List<Enseignant> listEnseignant;
```

I generate all getter and setter and tried with @jsonignore and it worked but this is not my purpose I want to show all Etudiant with a list of Cours and Enseignant

This is the model of Cours

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cours")
public class Cours implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long codeC;
private String libelleC;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Salle salleName;

@ManyToMany
private List<Etudiant> listEtu;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cours", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Enseignant> listEnseignants;
```

This is my etudiant controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/etudiant")
public class EtudiantController {
@Autowired
private EtudiantService etudiantsService;

@GetMapping(value = "/findEtudiant/{id}")
public Optional<Etudiant> findEtudiant(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    return etudiantsService.findEtudiant(Long.parseLong(id));
}

@PostMapping("/addEtudiant")
public Etudiant creeEtudiant(@RequestBody Etudiant etu) {
    etudiantsService.saveEtudiant(etu);
    return etu;
}

@PutMapping("/updateEtudiant")
public String UpdateEtudiant(@PathVariable @RequestBody Etudiant etu) {
    etudiantsService.saveEtudiant(etu);
    return "Student Updated Successfully !";
}

@GetMapping("/getAllEtudiant")
public List<Etudiant> getAllEtudiant() {
    return etudiantsService.ListEtudiant();
}

@DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteEtudiant/{id}")
public String deleteEtudiant(@PathVariable String id) {
    etudiantsService.removeEtudiant(Long.parseLong(id));
    return "Student Deleted Successfully";
}
```

}
This is my Etudiant Service Implementation

```
public class EtudiantImp implements EtudiantService{


@Autowired
EtudiantRepository etudiantRepository;

@Override
public List<Etudiant>ListEtudiant(){
    return etudiantRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public void saveEtudiant (Etudiant c) {
    etudiantRepository.save(c);
}

@Override
public void removeEtudiant(Long id) {
    etudiantRepository.deleteById(id);
}
@Override
public void updateEtudiant (Etudiant c)
{
etudiantRepository.save(c);
}
@Override
public Optional<Etudiant> findEtudiant(Long Id) {
    return etudiantRepository.findById(Id);
}
```

}
I also Tried Fetchtype EAGER but it's not working cuz it's not like parent-children class both can be parents cuz it's ManyToMany Relation!
This is the exact error in postman:
[image]

Comment: Will the error disappear if you add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to `Etudiant.listCours` annotation `@ManyToMany`? Show the code where load & where you you serialize. Probably hibernate loads list lazy and you serialize it outside of transaction thus the error.

Comment: I tried it that way and it doesn't work either I didn't create a custom serializer this is the random jackson&hibernate behaviour

Comment: Just add `@JsonIgnore` to `Etudiant.listCours`